# Moving object with a matrix ( 2d, f#)

Tags: matrix, f#, f#-interactive, drawing2d

I'm wondering if it is possible to move an object (for example a sphere) with a matrix. I've created a type: Ball and I've added a method:

```
let translateW (tx, ty) =
    m.Translate(tx, ty)
```

where `m` is `Drawing2d.Matrix()`

on the Paint method I wrote:

```
let g = e.Graphics      
g.Transform <- m
```

but I'm not updating a Ball object, I'm just translating the view... how can I move the ball instead?

Comment: Apply the matrix to the ball's center point?

Comment: so basically: P' = P*M

where * is multiply a Point for a matrix ?

Comment: Well, yes, I would think so. Why, do you see some problems with it?

Comment: mm no, but i would like to know if there were other ways for doing that.. do u have any ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. What's wrong with this way?

Comment: nothing at all, it's completely fine. as i said i was just wondering any other ways to accomplish the same result